# NextJS - Dynamic Routing with multiple fetch on 1 Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, fetch, next.js

I'm trying to rebuild my CRA Website with NextJS and I'm a little stuck on this [page](https://www.phidbac.fr/Liste-des-index) :

The middle container has 3 parts :

- List of Letters (no problem)
- List of **index** (only 1 fetch to get the list)
- Description of selected index (this one change every time a user selects a new **index** in the list)

It works perfectly fine with CRA.
So, with NextJS, I did the following :
The list of **index** has, for each index item, a link component to, for example:
`"https://www.phidbac.fr/Liste-des-index/50"`,

and a file **[id].js** in pages/Liste-des-index folder :

// fetch List and Description on each new select

```
const Indexes = ({ listeIndex, cours, id }) => {
  return (
    <>      
      <Layout>
        <PageIndex listeIndex={listeIndex} id={id} cours={cours} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
};

export default Indexes;

Indexes.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {

// Get the correct ID Description from URL
  let id = req.url;
  id = id.split("/")[2];

  const res = await fetch("https://www.phidbac.fr:4000/Indexes");
  const dataList = await res.json();
  const res1 = await fetch(`https://www.phidbac.fr:4000/Indexes/${id}`);
  const dataDescription = await res1.json();

  return {
    listeIndex: dataList,
    cours: dataDescription,
    id: id
  };
};
```

It's working, but this page does a complete reloading on each click, so it's slow and clearly not a good solution.

[Github Repository](https://github.com/Guarn/Phidbac-NextJS)

**How can I achieve something as smooth as the CRA version ?**

Thanks for helping :D

EDIT :

On this screenshot, you can see the delay between click and page loading, and the scroll container returning to the beginning.

[image: Example]

I just try to don't refresh the index list on each click and just change the description from the right side.

I've edited the git with your solution if you wanna try.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming convention you are using for your `[id-name].js` page, is part of the [Dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) feature of Next.js. By slightly modifying your code, using [`next/link` for Dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes), I think I managed to achieve what you requested.

[image]

At first, you have to modify `ListeIndex.tsx` and use `Link` component from `next/link` with props `href` and `as` (more about it on the link provided above and on the comments below)

```js
// ListeIndex.tsx

import Link from 'next/link'
// const { Link } = routes;

...

<Link
  key={element.id}
  prefetch={false}
  href="/Liste-des-index/[id-name]" // `href` points to page [id-name].js
  as={`/Liste-des-index/${element.id}-${element.nom // `as` holds the data you need to pass
    .replace(/\u202f/g, "-") 
    .replace(/\//g, "-")}`}> 

...
```

Then, you just need to modify your `[id-name].tsx`, and expect your data under `query` instead of `req`

```js
// [id-name].tsx

...

Indexes.getInitialProps = async ({ query }: any) => {
  const id = query['id-name'].split("-")[0]; // you should find your data under `query` parameter

...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping ! :D Unfortunately, even with these changes, I have a complete reloading.. The network tabs confirmed me the loading. If you scroll the second part (list of index) then choose another one, you can see the complete reload.

Comment: I'm not sure which is the second part. Can you give me an example? Anything I click from the list under `http://localhost:3000/Liste-des-index` seems to make a client-side navigation with no full page reload

Comment: Make sure you've changed your code as I suggested. You shouldn't face any issues with the list. Also notice that I changed the import for `Link` component. I'm using the component provided by `next/link` for this to work properly. If you still have an issue, push your code on your repo so I can take a look on it.

Comment: I just saw your new commit. Take a look on [this line](https://github.com/Guarn/Phidbac-NextJS/blob/master/components/Pages/Indexes/Components/ListeIndex.tsx#L21) of your code. `href` shouldn't be a dynamic prop, but instead this should point to the file you want to take control, like I do above: `href="/Liste-des-index/[id-name]"`, while on prop `as` you provide the details. If you change this line the everything should work as expected

Comment: OMG, i just understood, it's working ! And I have a better comprehension on the link components, Thanks again !

Comment: Happy I could help :)